# Correct way to label lists in GCP AutoML entity text model

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I want to create a model to extract info for PDFs containing purchase orders. I thought that I could create an AutoML text entity model for that task. The main doubt is what's the best way to handle with the article lists. How can I label each cell in order I can have a list of rows in the reuslt

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The labeling is very important, less than 10 labels to start would make it easy. As you will need at least a 100 entities labeled per label to train. remember you have three sets to label, train, test, validate. 100 for train, 30 for test and 30 for validate should suffice.
check the label tab often, it shows the break down of what has been labeled so far.
google's documentation is a good start. https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare

I ended up building a [Java client](https://github.com/googleapis/java-automl) to call predict on the model, sending it a list of files to process. the returned JSON has the entities by label for each file.